# Low K-fold accuracy for First Fold

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I created a text classifier, and I'm trying to utilize K-fold cross-validation.  I can't figure out why my first fold has an accuracy of 55% while my other folds are overfitting at 99-100% accuracy. My data set is a 5109x2 dataframe with columns df["Features"] as the features and df["Labels"] as labels.  df["Features"] has descriptors based off some product mapping keywords and are separated by commas as seen here: [Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb49N.png). I'm creating indicator variables based off the sub-features through countvectorizer().  This is the result of a 5-fold cv. [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C61xN.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

def train(classifier, X, y):
count_vect=CountVectorizer(min_df = 1,lowercase = False)
y=pd.Series(y)
X=count_vect.fit_transform(X)
y=count_vect.fit_transform(y)
kf=KFold(n_splits=5,shuffle=True)
k_fold=pd.Series(np.zeros(5))
for i,(train_index,test_index) in enumerate(kf.split(X)):
    print("Train",train_index, "Test",test_index)
    X_train,X_test=X[train_index],X[test_index]
    y_train,y_test=y[train_index],y[test_index]
    k_fold[i]=(print("For K=",i+1," Classifier accuracy= ",classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).score(X_test, y_test), "n = ",X_train.shape[0]))

train(MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=  (100,),activation='relu',random_state=2, max_iter=100, warm_start=True),df["Features"], df["Labels"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is entirely possible that this is just a result of the data. There is no reason to implement this by hand, scikit-learn has the [functionality](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) built in. If you want to test your implementation, try running the experiment using the `shuffle` parameter off to see if you get the same results.

It is best practice to shuffle your data anyway prior to running cross validation.

Comment: I've ran this a few times with the shuffle on, and the result is always the same, with the first fold having an accuracy rate in the 50's and the next four 99%.  I also ran it with the shuffle off, and the first fold is 25% accuracy, while the others are 99-100%.  I initially thought that it was because of high errors in the training data in the first fold, but with the shuffle on, I shouldn't be getting consistent low accuracy in the first fold and high accuracy in the others.  Without K-fold, just using train_test_split(), I can get it to around 75-80% consistently.

Comment: Hey I just realized what you mean by implementing using the built in functions.  After using cross_val_score(model,x,y,cv=5), I got the kfold to work. I'm still not sure why my implementation doesn't work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you update the code that works and check the answer then? Glad  to help.